# insert item to the front of a linked list? python

Tags: python, insert, linked-list, nodes, temporary

so I've been trying to insert an item to the front of a linked list, and it sort of works, but not fully. Here is what I have so far (there are more methods in the LinkedList class, but I omitted them because they weren't a problem):

```
class _Node():
    def __init__(self, data=None, link=None):
        self.data = data
        self.link = link

class LinkedList():
    def __init__(self):
        self.first = None
        self.size = 0

    def insert(self, ind, item):
        if self.first is None:
            self.first = _Node(item)
        elif ind == 0:                   # this is where the problem is. When I try to 
            temp = self.first            # insert a node to the front, it seems to
            temp.link = self.first.link  # forget about the rest of the nodes.
            self.first = _Node(item)
            self.first.link = temp  
        else:
            count = 0
            while count != ind - 1:
                count += 1
                self.first = self.first.link
            self.first.link = _Node(item, self.first.link)
        self.size += 1
```

say I have this in shell:

```
    >>> L = LinkedList()
    >>> L.insert(0, 5)
    >>> L.insert(1, 10)
    >>> L.insert(0, 20)
    >>> L[0]
    20
    >>> L[1]
    5
    >>> L[2]
    # and here is an error message, it says NoneType object has no attribute 'data'
```

so in my code above, what I'm trying to do is create a temporary node object that is identical to the first node object, I link that temporary node to the first nodes link, I create the new node, and I link that new node to the temporary one, but this doesn't work.
Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Why not use build-in data structure?

Comment: what do you mean? I'm new to programming, and I'm doing this to review for a test.

Comment: I mean python already has Linked list library

Comment: i dont know, I'm just supposed to know how to implement a linked list using nodes for my test, this is just the only part im stuck on.

Answer (score 2):

It seems as though those functions that you left out because they "weren't the problem", might actually be your problem...

Your code works if you ask for the data in each node in this way:

```
>>> L = LinkedList()
>>> L.insert(0,5)
>>> L.insert(1,10)
>>> L.insert(0,20)
>>> print L.first.data
20
>>> print L.first.link.data
5
>>> print L.first.link.link.data
10
```

You probably have an issue where you are defining `__getitem__`. Additionally, the part that you commented on can be rewritten in one line which may be more Pythonic.

```
temp = self.first
temp.link = self.first.link
self.first = _Node(item)
self.first.link = temp
```

The first two lines do nothing because `temp` is `self.first` so all you are saying is `self.first.link = self.first.link`. The next two can be written:

```
self.first = _Node(item, self.first)
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, note you actually don't need to special-case the empty list here:

```
def insert(self, ind, item):
    if ind == 0:
        newnode = _Node(item, self.first)
        self.first = newnode
```

Secondly, that isn't the problem. This code:

```
    else:
        count = 0
        while count != ind - 1:
            count += 1
            self.first = self.first.link
        self.first.link = _Node(item, self.first.link)
    self.size += 1
```

*changes* self.first in place, so it *forgets* what the first node was before. The smallest change to fix this would be:

```
    else:
        count = 0
        insert_point = self.first # use a local variable to walk the list
        while count != ind - 1:
            count += 1
            insert_point = insert_point.link
        insert_point.link = _Node(item, insert_point.link)
    self.size += 1
```